# Plot Pytorch vectors with TSNE

Tags: scipy, pytorch, tensor, tsne

I am using the [ESM-1b](https://github.com/facebookresearch/esm)  model to train it with some protein sequences. I already have the vectors and now I wanted to plot them using TSNE. However, when I try to pass the vectors to the TSNE model I get:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`
```

How should I plot the Pytorch vectors (they are Pytorch tensors, actually)?

The code I have so far:

```
sequence_representations = []
for i, (_, seq) in enumerate(new_list):
   sequence_representations.append(token_representations[i, 1 : len(seq) + 1].mean(0))
```

This is an example of the Pytorch tensors I have (sequence_representations):

```
[tensor([-0.0054,  0.1090, -0.0046,  ...,  0.0465,  0.0426, -0.0675]),
 tensor([-0.0025,  0.0228, -0.0521,  ..., -0.0611,  0.1010, -0.0103]),
 tensor([ 0.1168, -0.0189, -0.0121,  ..., -0.0388,  0.0586, -0.0285]),......
```

TSNE:

```
X_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2, learning_rate='auto', init='random').fit_transform(sequence_representations) #Where I get the error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using [scipy's `TSNE`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html), you'll need `sequence_representations` to be

> `ndarray` of shape (`n_samples`, `n_features`)

Right now have a list of pytorch tensors.

To convert `sequence_representations` to a numpy `ndarray` you'll need:

```py
seq_np = torch.stack(sequence_representations)  # from list of 1d tensors to a 2d tensor
seq_np = seq_np.numpy()  # convert to numpy
```